# Animating a flexbox from "auto"

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a flexbox from an "auto" state where most things are auto-sized to a state where one thing is sized.

```
|auto|this fills most space          |auto|

to

|auto|this...|auto                        |
```

demo: http://codepen.io/kaaaahhhhnnnn/pen/vOJpwo

When you hover you'll see what I want.  If you remove the comment in the CSS:

```
li
  // flex 1
```

you'll see that it now animates, but the sizes aren't what I want.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to get the 1st state with the `flex` properties existing and I can't figure out how to get the 2nd without it.  So I can't animate between the two.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that will let you animate in CSS to/from `auto`...`flexbox` or not

Comment: as I can see from your codepen you solved his yourself. 
Codepens have an auto save so they usually are bad for usage on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Persijn -- Eh, I kinda solved it.  If I specify the width manually it's fine.  I don't want to specify the width, however.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on the [flex](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property) shorthand is

> flex |none | [ <‘flex-grow’> <‘flex-shrink’>? || <‘flex-basis’> ]

Where the [flex-basis](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis-property) is:

> flex-basis | content | <‘width’> and the initial value : auto;

Is the flex-basis animatable?

> Animatable:   as width

So this property is by the specs only animatable as a width.

Auto is the same as its content. This property is not animatable.

[Flex-box w3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/)

Comment: thats a bummer. but thanks for explaining it like that :)